# Virtual Machine in C to run C

Tags: c, library, interpreter, virtual-machine

Basically ANOTHER follow up to [this review here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169118/c-virtual-machine-3rd-follow-up) but I've set about in completing the software project. Changes from the previous review is that I've added a complete script format with embedding API, changed the VM to register-based, and formed the calling convention similar to x64's. As an aspiring software engineer, this would be my first ever serious project that I've completed.

Remaining code on [GitHub](https://github.com/assyrianic/Tagha-Virtual-Machine/tree/c403b2c17b86f5f5f54b0d097333803555310626)

tagha.h

```
#ifndef TAGHA_H_INCLUDED
    #define TAGHA_H_INCLUDED


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <iso646.h>

/* For Colored Debugging Printing! */
#define KNRM    "\x1B[0m"   // Normal
#define KRED    "\x1B[31m"
#define KGRN    "\x1B[32m"
#define KYEL    "\x1B[33m"
#define KBLU    "\x1B[34m"
#define KMAG    "\x1B[35m"
#define KCYN    "\x1B[36m"
#define KWHT    "\x1B[37m"
#define RESET   "\033[0m"   // Reset obviously

#define LOOP_COUNTER    1800000000

/*
 * type generic Hashmap (uses 64-bit int as pointers to accomodate 32-bit and 64-bit)
 */
typedef struct KeyNode {
    uint64_t        m_pData;
    const char      *m_strKey;
    struct KeyNode  *m_pNext;
} KeyNode;

typedef struct Hashmap {
    uint32_t        size, count;
    struct KeyNode  **m_ppTable;
} Hashmap;

struct Tagha;
typedef struct Tagha    Tagha;


/* the most basic values in C.
 * In ALL of programming, there's only 4 fundamental data:
 *      Integers
 *      Floats
 *      Strings
 *      References
 */
typedef union CValue {
    bool Bool, *BoolPtr, BoolArr[8];
    int8_t Char, *CharPtr, CharArr[8];
    int16_t Short, *ShortPtr, ShortArr[4];
    int32_t Int32, *Int32Ptr, Int32Arr[2];
    int64_t Int64, *Int64Ptr;

    uint8_t UChar, *UCharPtr, UCharArr[8];
    uint16_t UShort, *UShortPtr, UShortArr[4];
    uint32_t UInt32, *UInt32Ptr, UInt32Arr[2];
    uint64_t UInt64, *UInt64Ptr;

    float Float, *FloatPtr, FloatArr[2];
    double Double, *DoublePtr;

    void *Ptr, **PtrPtr;
    const char *String, **StringPtr;
    char *Str, **StrPtr;
    union CValue *SelfPtr;
} CValue;

/* // Just gonna leave this here in case we ever need it.
#define SIMD_BYTES      32
typedef union SIMDCValue {
    union CValue cvalue;
    bool BoolSIMD[SIMD_BYTES];
    int8_t CharSIMD[SIMD_BYTES];
    int16_t ShortSIMD[SIMD_BYTES/2];
    int32_t Int32SIMD[SIMD_BYTES/4];
    int64_t Int64SIMD[SIMD_BYTES/8];

    uint8_t UCharSIMD[SIMD_BYTES];
    uint16_t UShortSIMD[SIMD_BYTES/2];
    uint32_t UInt32SIMD[SIMD_BYTES/4];
    uint64_t UInt64SIMD[SIMD_BYTES/8];

    float FloatIMD[SIMD_BYTES/4];
    double DoubleSIMD[SIMD_BYTES/8];
} SIMDCValue;
*/

//  API for scripts to call C/C++ host functions.
typedef     void (*fnNative_t)(struct Tagha *const pEnv, union CValue params[], union CValue *const pRetval, uint32_t uiArgc);

typedef struct NativeInfo {
    const char  *strName;   // use as string literals
    fnNative_t  pFunc;
} NativeInfo;


/* addressing modes
 *  immediate - simple constant value.
 *  register - register holds the exact data.
 *  register indirect - register holds memory address and dereferenced. Can be used as displacement as well.
 *  IPRelative - instruction ptr + offset. required for static data like global vars.
*/
enum AddrMode {
    Immediate   = 1,
    Register    = 2,
    RegIndirect = 4,
    //IPRelative    = 8,    // unused, will be replaced in the future with useful addr mode.
    Byte        = 16,
    TwoBytes    = 32,
    FourBytes   = 64,
    EightBytes  = 128,
};

// Register ID list
// 13 general purpose use registers + 3 reserved use.
enum RegID {
    // 'ras' is gen. purpose + accumulator
    // all native and tagha func return data that fits within 64-bits goes here.
    // natives can only return a single 8-byte piece of data.
    // if you need to return larger than 8 bytes...
    // use ras, rbs, and rcs. otherwise, return as pointer in ras.
    ras=0,rbs,rcs,

    // 12 more gen. purpose regs for whatever use.
    // when passing arguments, use registers rds to rms
    // since params are passed right to left.
    // put the rightmost arg in rms.
    // thus if you passed 10 args, the 1st arg would be in rds and 10th arg in rms.
    rds,
    res,rfs,rgs,
    rhs,ris,rjs,
    rks,rls,rms,

    // do not modify after this. Add more registers, if u need, above.
    rsp,rbp,    // stack ptrs, do not touch
    rip,        // instr ptr, do not touch as well.
    regsize     // for lazily updating RegID list
};


// for interactive mode.
/*
typedef struct TokenLine
{
    struct TokenLine *m_pNext;
    uint8_t *m_ucBytecode;
    uint32_t m_uiNumBytes;
} TokenLine;
*/

/* C global definitions.
 * usually C modules contain either functions or global vars visibly.
 * static variables and functions should NEVER be listed here as
 * static data of all types have internal linkage.
 * so a static local var, though "global", shouldn't come up in global var data
 */
enum DefType {
    DefGlobal=0,
    DefFunction=1,
};

typedef struct TaghaCDef {
    uint32_t m_uiOffset; // where is func or global var location in memory?
    uint8_t m_ucDefType; // type of definition, true if function.
} TaghaCDef;

struct Tagha {
    union CValue m_Regs[regsize];
    uint8_t
        *m_pMemory,         // script memory, entirely aligned by 8 bytes.
        *m_pStackSegment,   // stack segment ptr where the stack's lowest address lies.
        *m_pDataSegment,    // data segment is the address AFTER the stack segment ptr. Aligned by 8 bytes.
        *m_pTextSegment     // text segment is the address after the last global variable AKA the last opcode.
    ;
    // stores a C/C++ function ptr using the script-side name as the key.
    char **m_pstrNativeCalls;       // natives string table.
    struct Hashmap
        *m_pmapNatives, // native C/C++ interface hashmap.
        *m_pmapCDefs    // stores C definitions data like global vars and functions.
    ;
    union CValue *m_pArgv;  // using union to force char** size to 8 bytes.
    uint32_t
        m_uiMemsize,        // total size of m_pMemory
        m_uiInstrSize,      // size of the text segment
        m_uiMaxInstrs,      // max amount of instrs a script can execute.
        m_uiNatives,        // amount of natives the script uses.
        m_uiFuncs,          // how many functions the script has.
        m_uiGlobals         // how many globals variables the script has.
    ;
    int32_t m_iArgc;
    bool
        m_bSafeMode : 1,    // does the script want bounds checking?
        m_bDebugMode : 1,   // print debug info.
        m_bZeroFlag : 1     // conditional zero flag.
    ;
};

/*
 * I think you may wanna spend a bit thinking about what scope you want. A VM running 1 "script" (properly called a program, process, or thread) blurs the line between VM and interpreter. Having multiple programs means an OS program has to be built on top of the VM allowing it to run multiple programs concurrently.
 * 
 * There's no reason not to make a good VM, provide one or two compilers/interpreters in its native language. You don't have to write an OS to write code for the VM.
If it's generic enough, somebody can come along later and build an OS on top
* 
* Yeah, if you want it to be embedable, then just write an interpreter for one language with hooks to call it in other languages. If you need to run other languages on top, then go for a VM.
* 
* There you go, so you don't even really need a VM to embed C
* 
* You don't embed clang though. You build a backend so you can write binaries for tagha in any llvm language. You write an os kernel for tagha, allowing the compiler to be run in the machine.
* 
* A kernel is a program written for the machine that manages the filesystem, peripherals, and programs running on the machine. With a kernel, you can run compiling systems that are entirely contained in the machine.
Otherwise, you use an external machine to compile the binary, then move the binary into the machine to be run as its program.
* 
*  Probably the most direct way to do an REPL interpreter is to do the same thing you do compiling; collect text from the script until you have enough to compile a block of code and execute it. It'll be slow because it lacks optimization, but it shouldn't need many changes to your code.
*/


// tagha_exec.c
int32_t         Tagha_Exec(struct Tagha *const pSys);
const char      *RegIDToStr(enum RegID id);


// tagha_api.c
struct Tagha    *Tagha_New(void);
void            Tagha_Init(struct Tagha *pSys);
void            Tagha_LoadScriptByName(struct Tagha *pSys, char *filename);
void            Tagha_LoadScriptFromMemory(struct Tagha *pSys, void *pMemory, uint64_t memsize);
bool            Tagha_RegisterNatives(const struct Tagha *pSys, struct NativeInfo arrNatives[]);
void            Tagha_Free(struct Tagha *pSys);
int32_t         Tagha_RunScript(struct Tagha *pSys);
int32_t         Tagha_CallFunc(struct Tagha *pSys, const char *strFunc);

#ifndef FREE_MEM
    #define FREE_MEM(ptr)   if( (ptr) ) free( (ptr) ), (ptr)=NULL
#endif

void            Tagha_BuildFromFile(struct Tagha *pSys, const char *strFilename);
void            Tagha_BuildFromPtr(struct Tagha *pSys, void *pProgram, uint64_t Programsize);

void            Tagha_PrintPtrs(const struct Tagha *pSys);
void            Tagha_PrintStack(const struct Tagha *pSys);
void            Tagha_PrintData(const struct Tagha *pSys);
void            Tagha_PrintInstrs(const struct Tagha *pSys);
void            Tagha_PrintRegData(const struct Tagha *pSys);
void            Tagha_Reset(struct Tagha *pSys);

void            *Tagha_GetGlobalByName(const struct Tagha *pSys, const char *strGlobalName);
void            Tagha_PushValues(struct Tagha *pSys, uint32_t uiArgs, union CValue values[]);
union CValue    Tagha_PopValue(struct Tagha *pSys);
void            Tagha_SetCmdArgs(struct Tagha *pSys, char *argv[]);

uint32_t        Tagha_GetMemSize(const struct Tagha *pSys);
uint32_t        Tagha_GetInstrSize(const struct Tagha *pSys);
uint32_t        Tagha_GetMaxInstrs(const struct Tagha *pSys);
uint32_t        Tagha_GetNativeCount(const struct Tagha *pSys);
uint32_t        Tagha_GetFuncCount(const struct Tagha *pSys);
uint32_t        Tagha_GetGlobalsCount(const struct Tagha *pSys);
bool            Tagha_IsSafemodeActive(const struct Tagha *pSys);
bool            Tagha_IsDebugActive(const struct Tagha *pSys);
void            Tagha_PrintErr(const struct Tagha *pSys, const char *funcname, const char *err, ...);

// ds.c
struct Hashmap  *Map_New(void);
void            Map_Init(struct Hashmap *map);
void            Map_Free(struct Hashmap *map);
uint64_t        Map_Len(const struct Hashmap *map);

void            Map_Rehash(struct Hashmap *map);
bool            Map_Insert(struct Hashmap *map, const char *strKey, uint64_t pData);
uint64_t        Map_Get(const struct Hashmap *map, const char *strKey);
void            Map_Set(const struct Hashmap *map, const char *strKey, uint64_t pData);
void            Map_Delete(struct Hashmap *map, const char *strKey);
bool            Map_HasKey(const struct Hashmap *map, const char *strKey);
const char      *Map_GetKey(const struct Hashmap *map, const char *strKey);

/*
void            Map_Rehash_int(struct Hashmap *);
bool            Map_Insert_int(struct Hashmap *, const uint64_t, void *);
void            *Map_Get_int(const struct Hashmap *, const uint64_t);
void            Map_Delete_int(struct Hashmap *, const uint64_t);
bool            Map_HasKey_int(const struct Hashmap *, const uint64_t);
*/
uint64_t        gethash64(const char *strKey);
uint32_t        gethash32(const char *strKey);
uint64_t        int64hash(uint64_t x);
uint32_t        int32hash(uint32_t x);


/*
*   r = register is first operand
*   m = memory address is first operand
*/
#define INSTR_SET \
    X(halt) \
    /* single operand opcodes */ \
    /* stack ops */ \
    X(push) X(pop) \
    /* unary arithmetic and bitwise ops */ \
    X(neg) X(inc) X(dec) X(bnot) \
    /* jump ops */ \
    X(jmp) X(jz) X(jnz) \
    \
    /* subroutine ops */ \
    X(call) X(ret) X(callnat) \
    \
    /* two operand opcodes */ \
    X(movr) X(movm) X(lea) \
    /* signed and unsigned integer arithmetic ops */ \
    X(addr) X(addm) X(uaddr) X(uaddm) \
    X(subr) X(subm) X(usubr) X(usubm) \
    X(mulr) X(mulm) X(umulr) X(umulm) \
    X(divr) X(divm) X(udivr) X(udivm) \
    X(modr) X(modm) X(umodr) X(umodm) \
    /* bitwise ops */ \
    X(shrr) X(shrm) X(shlr) X(shlm) \
    X(andr) X(andm) X(orr) X(orm) X(xorr) X(xorm) \
    /* comparison ops */ \
    X(ltr) X(ltm) X(ultr) X(ultm) \
    X(gtr) X(gtm) X(ugtr) X(ugtm) \
    X(cmpr) X(cmpm) X(ucmpr) X(ucmpm) \
    X(neqr) X(neqm) X(uneqr) X(uneqm) \
    X(reset) \
    \
    /* floating point opcodes */ \
    X(int2float) X(int2dbl) X(float2dbl) X(dbl2float) \
    X(faddr) X(faddm) X(fsubr) X(fsubm) X(fmulr) X(fmulm) X(fdivr) X(fdivm) \
    X(fneg) X(fltr) X(fltm) X(fgtr) X(fgtm) X(fcmpr) X(fcmpm) X(fneqr) X(fneqm) \
    /* misc opcodes */ \
    X(nop) \

#define X(x)    x,
enum InstrSet{ INSTR_SET };
#undef X

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  // TAGHA_H_INCLUDED
```

tagha_api.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "tagha.h"


/* Tagha File Structure (Dec 23, 2017)
 * ------------------------------ start of header ------------------------------
 * 2 bytes: magic verifier ==> 0xC0DE
 * 4 bytes: stack segment size (aligned by 8 bytes)
 * 4 bytes: data segment size
 * 1 byte: safemode and debugmode flags
 * ------------------------------ end of header ------------------------------
 * .natives table
 * 4 bytes: amount of natives
 * n bytes: native table
 *      4 bytes: string size + '\0' of native string
 *      n bytes: native string.
 * 
 * .functions table
 * 4 bytes: amount of functions
 * n bytes: functions table
 *      4 bytes: string size + '\0' of func string
 *      n bytes: function string
 *      4 bytes: offset
 * 
 * .globalvars table
 * 4 bytes: amount of global vars
 * n bytes: global vars table
 *      4 bytes: string size + '\0' of global var string
 *      n bytes: global var string
 *      4 bytes: offset
 * 
 * n bytes: .data section initial values.
 * n bytes: .text section
 */

static uint64_t get_file_size(FILE *pFile);
static uint32_t scripthdr_read_natives_table(struct Tagha **const ppSys, FILE **const ppFile);
static uint32_t scripthdr_read_func_table(struct Tagha **const ppSys, FILE **const ppFile);
static uint32_t scripthdr_read_global_table(struct Tagha **const ppSys, FILE **const ppFile);


struct Tagha *Tagha_New(void)
{
    struct Tagha *pNewVM = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Tagha));
    Tagha_Init(pNewVM);
    return pNewVM;
}

void Tagha_Init(struct Tagha *restrict const pSys)
{
    if( !pSys )
        return;

    *pSys = (struct Tagha){0};

    if( !pSys->m_pmapCDefs ) {
        pSys->m_pmapCDefs = Map_New();
        // if we can't allocate our C Definitions
        // we can't run code in general as the definitions
        // contain functions and global vars!
        if( !pSys->m_pmapCDefs ) {
            printf("[%sTagha Init Error%s]: **** %sUnable to initialize C Definitions Map%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
            return;
        }
        else Map_Init(pSys->m_pmapCDefs);
    }
    if( !pSys->m_pmapNatives ) {
        pSys->m_pmapNatives = Map_New();
        if( !pSys->m_pmapNatives )
            printf("[%sTagha Init Error%s]: **** %sUnable to initialize Native Map%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
        else Map_Init(pSys->m_pmapNatives);
    }
    if( !pSys->m_pArgv ) {
        pSys->m_iArgc = 0;
        pSys->m_pArgv = calloc(pSys->m_iArgc+1, sizeof(union CValue));
        if( !pSys->m_pArgv )
            printf("[%sTagha Init Error%s]: **** %sUnable to initialize Command-line Args String Vector%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
        else pSys->m_pArgv[pSys->m_iArgc].Str = NULL;
    }
}

static bool is_c_file(const char *restrict filename)
{
    if( !filename )
        return false;

    // iterate to end of string and then check backwards.
    while( *++filename );
    int16_t i = *(int16_t *)(filename-2);
    return( i==0x632E || i==0x432E );
}

static bool is_tbc_file(const char *restrict filename)
{
    if( !filename )
        return false;

    // iterate to end of string and then check backwards.
    while( *++filename );
    int32_t i = *(int32_t *)(filename-4);
    return( i==0x6362742E || i==0x4342542E );
}


void Tagha_LoadScriptByName(struct Tagha *const pSys, char *restrict strFilename)
{
    if( !pSys )
        return;

    // allocate our script.
    Tagha_BuildFromFile(pSys, strFilename);

    // set up our standard I/O streams
    // and global self-referencing script ptr
    // Downside is that the script-side host var MUST be a pointer.
    if( pSys->m_pmapCDefs ) {
        FILE **ppFile=Tagha_GetGlobalByName(pSys, "stdin");
        if( ppFile )
            *ppFile = stdin;

        ppFile = Tagha_GetGlobalByName(pSys, "stderr");
        if( ppFile )
            *ppFile = stderr;

        ppFile = Tagha_GetGlobalByName(pSys, "stdout");
        if( ppFile )
            *ppFile = stdout;

        struct Tagha **ppSelf=Tagha_GetGlobalByName(pSys, "self");
        if( ppSelf )
            *ppSelf = pSys;
    }
}

void Tagha_LoadScriptFromMemory(struct Tagha *const pSys, void *restrict pMemory, const uint64_t memsize)
{
    if( !pSys )
        return;

    // allocate our script.
    Tagha_BuildFromPtr(pSys, pMemory, memsize);

    // set up our standard I/O streams
    // and global self-referencing script ptr
    // Downside is that the script-side host var MUST be a pointer.
    if( pSys->m_pmapCDefs ) {
        FILE **ppFile=Tagha_GetGlobalByName(pSys, "stdin");
        if( ppFile )
            *ppFile = stdin;

        ppFile = Tagha_GetGlobalByName(pSys, "stderr");
        if( ppFile )
            *ppFile = stderr;

        ppFile = Tagha_GetGlobalByName(pSys, "stdout");
        if( ppFile )
            *ppFile = stdout;

        struct Tagha **ppSelf=Tagha_GetGlobalByName(pSys, "self");
        if( ppSelf )
            *ppSelf = pSys;
    }
}


bool Tagha_RegisterNatives(const struct Tagha *restrict const pSys, struct NativeInfo arrNatives[])
{
    if( !pSys or !pSys->m_pmapNatives or !arrNatives )
        return false;

    for( struct NativeInfo *n=arrNatives ; n->pFunc and n->strName ; n++ )
        Map_Insert(pSys->m_pmapNatives, n->strName, (uintptr_t)n->pFunc);
    return true;
}


int32_t Tagha_RunScript(struct Tagha *restrict const pSys)
{
    if( !pSys or !pSys->m_pMemory )
        return -1;

    // make sure 'main' exists.
    else if( !pSys->m_pmapCDefs ) {
        Tagha_PrintErr(pSys, __func__, "Cannot call main with a NULL definition table!");
        return -1;
    }
    // make sure we have the memory for running.
    else if( ((pSys->m_Regs[rsp].UCharPtr-pSys->m_pMemory)-32) >= pSys->m_uiMemsize ) {
        Tagha_PrintErr(pSys, __func__, "stack overflow!");
        return -1;
    }
    // get instruction offset to main.
    struct TaghaCDef *pMainData = (struct TaghaCDef *)(uintptr_t)Map_Get(pSys->m_pmapCDefs, "main");
    if( !pMainData or pMainData->m_ucDefType != DefFunction ) {
        Tagha_PrintErr(pSys, __func__, "function \'main\' doesn't exist!");
        return -1;
    }
    pSys->m_Regs[rip].UCharPtr = pSys->m_pMemory + pMainData->m_uiOffset;

    // push argv and argc to registers.
    // use 'uintptr_t' so we can force 4-byte pointers as 8-byte.
    pSys->m_Regs[res].UInt64 = (uintptr_t)pSys->m_pArgv;
    pSys->m_Regs[rds].Int64 = pSys->m_iArgc;

    (--pSys->m_Regs[rsp].SelfPtr)->Int64 = -1L; // push bullshit ret address.
    (--pSys->m_Regs[rsp].SelfPtr)->UInt64 = pSys->m_Regs[rbp].UInt64; // push rbp

    if( pSys->m_bDebugMode )
        printf("Tagha_RunScript :: pushed argc: %" PRIi32 " and argv %p\n", pSys->m_iArgc, pSys->m_pArgv);

    return Tagha_Exec(pSys);
}

int32_t Tagha_CallFunc(struct Tagha *restrict const pSys, const char *restrict strFunc)
{
    if( !pSys or !strFunc )
        return -1;

    else if( !pSys->m_pmapCDefs ) {
        Tagha_PrintErr(pSys, __func__, "Cannot call functions using a NULL function table!");
        return -1;
    }
    else if( ((pSys->m_Regs[rsp].UCharPtr-pSys->m_pMemory)-16) >= pSys->m_uiMemsize ) {
        Tagha_PrintErr(pSys, __func__, "stack overflow!");
        return -1;
    }

    struct TaghaCDef *pFuncData = (struct TaghaCDef *)(uintptr_t)Map_Get(pSys->m_pmapCDefs, strFunc);
    if( !pFuncData or pFuncData->m_ucDefType != DefFunction) {
        Tagha_PrintErr(pSys, __func__, "function \'%s\' doesn't exist!", strFunc);
        return -1;
    }

    // save return address.
    (--pSys->m_Regs[rsp].SelfPtr)->UInt64 = (uintptr_t)pSys->m_Regs[rip].UCharPtr+1;

    // jump to the function entry address.
    pSys->m_Regs[rip].UCharPtr = pSys->m_pMemory + pFuncData->m_uiOffset;

    // push bp and copy sp to bp.
    (--pSys->m_Regs[rsp].SelfPtr)->UInt64 = pSys->m_Regs[rbp].UInt64;

    return Tagha_Exec(pSys);
}


// need this to determine the text segment size.
static uint64_t get_file_size(FILE *restrict pFile)
{
    uint64_t size = 0L;
    if( !pFile )
        return size;

    if( !fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END) ) {
        size = (uint64_t)ftell(pFile);
        rewind(pFile);
    }
    return size;
}

static uint32_t scripthdr_read_natives_table(struct Tagha **const ppSys, FILE **const ppFile)
{
    if( !*ppSys or !*ppFile )
        return 0;

    struct Tagha *pSys = *ppSys;
    uint32_t    bytecount = 0;
    int32_t     ignores = 0;

    // see if the script is using any natives.
    pSys->m_pstrNativeCalls = NULL;
    ignores = fread(&pSys->m_uiNatives, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, *ppFile);
    printf("[Tagha Load Script] :: Amount of Natives: \'%" PRIu32 "\'\n", pSys->m_uiNatives);
    bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);
    if( !pSys->m_uiNatives )
        return bytecount;

    // script has natives? Copy their names so we can use them on VM natives hashmap later.
    pSys->m_pstrNativeCalls = calloc(pSys->m_uiNatives, sizeof(char *));
    if( !pSys->m_pstrNativeCalls ) {
        printf("[%sTagha Load Script Error%s]: **** %sFailed to allocate memory for Native Table%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
        Tagha_Free(pSys), *ppSys = NULL;
        fclose(*ppFile), *ppFile=NULL;
        return 0;
    }

    for( uint32_t i=0 ; i<pSys->m_uiNatives ; i++ ) {
        uint32_t str_size;
        ignores = fread(&str_size, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, *ppFile);
        bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);

        // allocate memory to hold the native's name.
        pSys->m_pstrNativeCalls[i] = calloc(str_size, sizeof(char));
        if( !pSys->m_pstrNativeCalls[i] ) {
            printf("[%sTagha Load Script Error%s]: **** %sFailed to allocate memory for Native String%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
            Tagha_Free(pSys), *ppSys = NULL;
            fclose(*ppFile), *ppFile=NULL;
            return 0;
        }

        // read in the native's name.
        ignores = fread(pSys->m_pstrNativeCalls[i], sizeof(char), str_size, *ppFile);
        bytecount += str_size;
        printf("[Tagha Load Script] :: Copied Native Name: \'%s\' @ %p\n", pSys->m_pstrNativeCalls[i], pSys->m_pstrNativeCalls+i);
    }
    pSys = NULL;
    return bytecount;
}

static uint32_t scripthdr_read_func_table(struct Tagha **const ppSys, FILE **const ppFile)
{
    if( !*ppSys or !*ppFile )
        return 0;

    struct Tagha *pSys = *ppSys;
    uint32_t    bytecount = 0;
    int32_t     ignore_warns = 0;

    // see if the script has its own functions.
    // This table is so host or other script can call these functions by name or address.
    ignore_warns = fread(&pSys->m_uiFuncs, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, *ppFile);
    bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);
    if( !pSys->m_uiFuncs )
        return bytecount;

    // copy the function data from the header.
    for( uint32_t i=0 ; i<pSys->m_uiFuncs ; i++ ) {
        uint32_t str_size;
        ignore_warns = fread(&str_size, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, *ppFile);
        bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);

        // allocate the hashmap function key.
        char *strFunc = calloc(str_size, sizeof(char));
        if( !strFunc ) {
            printf("[%sTagha Load Script Error%s]: **** %sFailed to allocate memory for Func Table String%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
            Tagha_Free(pSys), *ppSys = NULL;
            fclose(*ppFile), *ppFile=NULL;
            return 0;
        } /* if */
        ignore_warns = fread(strFunc, sizeof(char), str_size, *ppFile);
        bytecount += str_size;

        // copy func's header data to our table
        // then store the table to our function hashmap with the key
        // we allocated earlier.
        struct TaghaCDef *pFuncData = calloc(1, sizeof(struct TaghaCDef));
        if( !pFuncData ) {
            printf("[%sTagha Load Script Error%s]: **** %sFailed to allocate memory for Func Data%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
            Tagha_Free(pSys), *ppSys = NULL;
            fclose(*ppFile), *ppFile=NULL;
            return 0;
        } /* if */

        ignore_warns = fread(&pFuncData->m_uiOffset, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, *ppFile);
        bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);
        printf("[Tagha Load Script] :: Copied Function name \'%s\' | offset: %" PRIu32 "\n", strFunc, pFuncData->m_uiOffset);
        pFuncData->m_ucDefType = DefFunction;
        Map_Insert(pSys->m_pmapCDefs, strFunc, (uintptr_t)pFuncData);
        strFunc = NULL; pFuncData = NULL;
    } /* for */
    pSys = NULL;
    return bytecount;
}

static uint32_t scripthdr_read_global_table(struct Tagha **const ppSys, FILE **const ppFile)
{
    if( !*ppSys or !*ppFile )
        return 0;

    struct Tagha *pSys = *ppSys;
    uint32_t    bytecount = 0;
    int32_t     ignore_warns = 0;

    // check if the script has global variables.
    ignore_warns = fread(&pSys->m_uiGlobals, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, *ppFile);
    printf("[Tagha Load Script] :: Amount of Global Vars: %" PRIu32 "\n", pSys->m_uiGlobals);
    bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);
    uint32_t globalbytes = 0;
    if( !pSys->m_uiGlobals )
        return bytecount;

    for( uint32_t i=0 ; i<pSys->m_uiGlobals ; i++ ) {
        uint32_t str_size;
        ignore_warns = fread(&str_size, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, *ppFile);
        bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);
        // allocate string to use as a key for our global var.
        char *strGlobal = calloc(str_size, sizeof(char));
        if( !strGlobal ) {
            printf("[%sTagha Load Script Error%s]: **** %sFailed to allocate memory for Global Var String%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
            Tagha_Free(pSys), *ppSys = NULL;
            fclose(*ppFile), *ppFile=NULL;
            return 0;
        }
        ignore_warns = fread(strGlobal, sizeof(char), str_size, *ppFile);
        bytecount += str_size;

        // read the global var's data from the header and add it to our hashmap.
        // same procedure as our function hashmap.
        struct TaghaCDef *pGlobalData = calloc(1, sizeof(struct TaghaCDef));
        if( !pGlobalData ) {
            printf("[%sTagha Load Script Error%s]: **** %sFailed to allocate memory for Global Var Table%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
            Tagha_Free(pSys), *ppSys = NULL;
            fclose(*ppFile), *ppFile=NULL;
            return 0;
        } /* if */

        ignore_warns = fread(&pGlobalData->m_uiOffset, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, *ppFile);
        bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);

        printf("[Tagha Load Script] :: copied global var's name: \'%s\' | offset: %" PRIu32 "\n", strGlobal, pGlobalData->m_uiOffset);

        // insert the global var's table to our hashmap.
        pGlobalData->m_ucDefType = DefGlobal;
        Map_Insert(pSys->m_pmapCDefs, strGlobal, (uintptr_t)pGlobalData);
        strGlobal = NULL; pGlobalData = NULL;
    } /* for( uint32_t i=0 ; i<pSys->m_uiGlobals ; i++ ) */
    pSys = NULL;
    return bytecount;
}

void Tagha_BuildFromFile(struct Tagha *pSys, const char *restrict strFilename)
{
    if( !pSys or !pSys->m_pmapCDefs or !strFilename )
        return;

    // open up our script in read-only binary mode.
    FILE *pFile = fopen(strFilename, "rb");
    if( !pFile ) {
        printf("[%sTagha Load Script Error%s]: **** %sFile not found: \'%s\'%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, strFilename, RESET);
        return;
    }

    // get_file_size stays here, it'll rewind the file 'cursor' back to beginning.
    const uint64_t filesize = get_file_size(pFile);

    uint32_t bytecount = 0; // bytecount is for separating the header data from the actual instruction stream.
    uint16_t verify;
    int32_t ignore_warns;
    ignore_warns = fread(&verify, sizeof(uint16_t), 1, pFile);
    bytecount += sizeof(uint16_t);

    if( verify != 0xC0DE ) {
        printf("[%sTagha Load Script Error%s]: **** %sUnknown or Invalid script file format%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
        goto error;
    }
    puts("[Tagha Load Script] :: Verified Script!\n");

    // get stack memory size.
    uint32_t stacksize, datasize;
    ignore_warns = fread(&stacksize, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, pFile);
    bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);
    stacksize = stacksize<0x1000 ? 0x1000 : stacksize;

    // align by 8 bytes
    stacksize = stacksize + 7 & -8;

    // get static data (global vars, string literals) memory size.
    ignore_warns = fread(&datasize, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, pFile);
    bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);

    // check if the script is either in safemode or debug mode.
    char modeflags;
    ignore_warns = fread(&modeflags, sizeof(char), 1, pFile);
    bytecount += sizeof(char);
    pSys->m_bSafeMode = (modeflags & 1) >= 1;

    pSys->m_bDebugMode = (modeflags & 2) >= 1;
    if( pSys->m_bDebugMode )
        printf("[Tagha Load Script] :: Stack Size: %" PRIu32 "\n[Tagha Load Script] :: Data Size: %" PRIu32 "\n[Tagha Load Script] :: Safe Mode: %" PRIu32 "\n[Tagha Load Script] :: Debug Mode: %" PRIu32 "\n", stacksize, datasize, pSys->m_bSafeMode, pSys->m_bDebugMode);

    bytecount += scripthdr_read_natives_table(&pSys, &pFile);
    bytecount += scripthdr_read_func_table(&pSys, &pFile);
    if( !pFile )
        return;

    bytecount += scripthdr_read_global_table(&pSys, &pFile);
    if( !pFile )
        return;

    pSys->m_uiMaxInstrs = LOOP_COUNTER; // helps to stop infinite/runaway loops


    // header data is finished, subtract the filesize with the bytecount
    // and data segment size to get the size of our instruction stream.
    // If the instruction stream is invalid, we can't load the script.
    printf("[Tagha Load Script] :: Header Byte Count: %" PRIu32 "\n", bytecount);
    pSys->m_uiInstrSize = filesize - bytecount - datasize;

    pSys->m_uiMemsize = stacksize + datasize + pSys->m_uiInstrSize;
    pSys->m_pMemory = calloc(pSys->m_uiMemsize, sizeof(uint8_t));

    // scripts NEED memory, if memory is invalid then we can't use the script.
    if( !pSys->m_pMemory ) {
        printf("[%sTagha Load Script Error%s]: **** %sFailed to allocate memory for script%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
        Tagha_Free(pSys);
        goto error;
    }

    /*  +------------------+
        |    stack   |     |      highest address
        |            v     |
        |                  |
        |                  |
        |                  |
        |                  |
        |                  |
        |                  |
        +------------------+      stack segment
        | data segment     |
        +------------------+
        | text segment     |      lowest address
        +------------------+
    */

    // set up the stack ptrs to the top of the stack.
    pSys->m_Regs[rsp].UCharPtr = pSys->m_Regs[rbp].UCharPtr = pSys->m_pMemory + (pSys->m_uiMemsize-1);

    // set up our stack segment by taking the top of the stack and subtracting it with the size.
    pSys->m_pStackSegment = pSys->m_Regs[rsp].UCharPtr - (stacksize-1);

    // set up the data segment by taking the stack segment - 1
    pSys->m_pDataSegment = pSys->m_pStackSegment - 1;

    // set up the text segment similar to how the stack ptrs are set up
    pSys->m_pTextSegment = pSys->m_pMemory + (pSys->m_uiInstrSize-1);

    // copy the initialized values to the data segment if there's any global values.
    ignore_warns = fread(pSys->m_pTextSegment+1, sizeof(uint8_t), pSys->m_pDataSegment-pSys->m_pTextSegment, pFile);

    // instruction stream is valid, copy every last instruction.
    ignore_warns = fread(pSys->m_pMemory, sizeof(uint8_t), pSys->m_uiInstrSize, pFile);

    puts("Tagha_BuildFromFile :: Finished Reading Header!\n");
error:;
    fclose(pFile), pFile=NULL;
}

void Tagha_BuildFromPtr(struct Tagha *restrict pSys, void *pProgram, const uint64_t Programsize)
{
    if( !pSys or !pSys->m_pmapCDefs or !pProgram )
        return;

    union CValue Reader = (union CValue){.UCharPtr=pProgram};
    uint32_t bytecount = 0; // bytecount is for separating the header data from the actual instruction stream.

    if( *Reader.UShortPtr != 0xC0DE ) {
        printf("[%sTagha Load Script Error%s]: **** %sUnknown or Invalid Script file format%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
        return;
    }
    bytecount += sizeof(uint16_t);
    Reader.UShortPtr++;

    puts("[Tagha Load Script Ptr] :: Verified Script!\n");

    // get stack memory size.
    uint32_t stacksize, datasize;
    stacksize = *Reader.UInt32Ptr++;
    bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);

    stacksize = stacksize<0x1000 ? 0x1000 : stacksize;
    stacksize = stacksize + 7 & -8; // align size by 8 bytes
    printf("[Tagha Load Script Ptr] :: Stack Size: %" PRIu32 "\n", stacksize);

    // get static data (global vars, string literals) memory size.
    datasize = *Reader.UInt32Ptr++;
    bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);
    printf("[Tagha Load Script Ptr] :: Data Size: %" PRIu32 "\n", datasize);


    char modeflags = *Reader.CharPtr++;
    bytecount += sizeof(char);
    pSys->m_bSafeMode = (modeflags & 1) >= 1;
    printf("[Tagha Load Script Ptr] :: script Safe Mode: %" PRIu32 "\n", pSys->m_bSafeMode);

    pSys->m_bDebugMode = (modeflags & 2) >= 1;
    printf("[Tagha Load Script Ptr] :: script Debug Mode: %" PRIu32 "\n", pSys->m_bDebugMode);

    // get natives table.
    pSys->m_uiNatives = *Reader.UInt32Ptr++;
    bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);
    if( pSys->m_uiNatives ) {
        // script has natives? Copy their names so we can use them on VM natives hashmap later.
        pSys->m_pstrNativeCalls = calloc(pSys->m_uiNatives, sizeof(char *));
        if( !pSys->m_pstrNativeCalls ) {
            printf("[%sTagha Load Script Error%s]: **** %sFailed to allocate memory for Native Table%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
            Tagha_Free(pSys);
            return;
        } /* if */

        for( uint32_t i=0 ; i<pSys->m_uiNatives ; i++ ) {
            uint32_t str_size = *Reader.UInt32Ptr++;
            bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);

            // allocate memory to hold the native's name.
            pSys->m_pstrNativeCalls[i] = calloc(str_size, sizeof(char));
            if( !pSys->m_pstrNativeCalls[i] ) {
                printf("[%sTagha Load Script Error%s]: **** %sFailed to allocate memory for Native String%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
                Tagha_Free(pSys);
                return;
            }

            // read in the native's name.
            memcpy(pSys->m_pstrNativeCalls[i], Reader.Ptr, str_size);
            bytecount += str_size;
            Reader.UCharPtr += str_size;
            printf("[Tagha Load Script Ptr] :: copied native name \'%s\'\n", pSys->m_pstrNativeCalls[i]);
        } /* for( ... ) */
    } /* if( pSys->m_uiNatives ) */

    // see if the script has its own functions.
    // This table is so host or other script can call these functions by name or address.
    pSys->m_uiFuncs = *Reader.UInt32Ptr++;
    bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);

    // if we have no functions, that means main is missing...
    if( pSys->m_uiFuncs ) {
        // copy the function data from the header.
        for( uint32_t i=0 ; i<pSys->m_uiFuncs ; i++ ) {
            uint32_t str_size = *Reader.UInt32Ptr++;
            bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);

            // allocate the hashmap function key.
            char *strFunc = calloc(str_size, sizeof(char));
            if( !strFunc ) {
                printf("[%sTagha Load Script Error%s]: **** %sFailed to allocate memory for Func Table String%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
                Tagha_Free(pSys);
                return;
            }
            memcpy(strFunc, Reader.Ptr, str_size);
            Reader.UCharPtr += str_size;
            bytecount += str_size;

            // copy func's header data to our table
            // then store the table to our function hashmap with the key
            // we allocated earlier.
            struct TaghaCDef *pFuncData = calloc(1, sizeof(struct TaghaCDef));
            if( !pFuncData ) {
                printf("[%sTagha Load Script Error%s]: **** %sFailed to allocate memory for Func Offset%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
                Tagha_Free(pSys);
                return;
            } /* if */
            pFuncData->m_uiOffset = *Reader.UInt32Ptr++;
            bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);

            printf("[Tagha Load Script Ptr] :: Copied Function name \'%s\' | offset: %" PRIu32 "\n", strFunc, pFuncData->m_uiOffset);
            pFuncData->m_ucDefType = DefFunction;
            Map_Insert(pSys->m_pmapCDefs, strFunc, (uintptr_t)pFuncData);
            strFunc = NULL;
        } /* for( uint32_t i=0 ; i<pSys->m_uiFuncs ; i++ ) */
    }
    else {
        printf("[%sTagha Load Script Error%s]: **** %sFailed to allocate memory for Native String%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
        Tagha_Free(pSys);
        return;
    }

    // check if the script has global variables.
    pSys->m_uiGlobals = *Reader.UInt32Ptr++;
    printf("[Tagha Load Script Ptr] :: Amount of Global Vars: %" PRIu32 "\n", pSys->m_uiGlobals);
    bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);

    uint32_t globalbytes = 0;
    if( pSys->m_uiGlobals ) {
        for( uint32_t i=0 ; i<pSys->m_uiGlobals ; i++ ) {
            uint32_t str_size = *Reader.UInt32Ptr++;
            bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);
            // allocate string to use as a key for our global var.
            char *strGlobal = calloc(str_size, sizeof(char));
            if( !strGlobal ) {
                printf("[%sTagha Load Script Error%s]: **** %sFailed to allocate memory for Global Var String%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
                Tagha_Free(pSys);
                return;
            }
            memcpy(strGlobal, Reader.Ptr, str_size);
            Reader.UCharPtr += str_size;
            bytecount += str_size;

            // read the global var's data from the header and add it to our hashmap.
            // same procedure as our function hashmap.
            struct TaghaCDef *pGlobalData = calloc(1, sizeof(struct TaghaCDef));
            if( !pGlobalData ) {
                printf("[%sTagha Load Script Error%s]: **** %sFailed to allocate memory for Global Var Offset%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
                Tagha_Free(pSys);
                return;
            } /* if */
            pGlobalData->m_uiOffset = *Reader.UInt32Ptr++;
            bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);

            printf("[Tagha Load Script Ptr] :: copied global var's name: \'%s\' | offset: %" PRIu32 "\n", strGlobal, pGlobalData->m_uiOffset);

            // insert the global var's table to our hashmap.
            pGlobalData->m_ucDefType = DefGlobal;
            Map_Insert(pSys->m_pmapCDefs, strGlobal, (uintptr_t)pGlobalData);
            strGlobal = NULL;
        } /* for( uint32_t i=0 ; i<pSys->m_uiGlobals ; i++ ) */
    }

    pSys->m_uiMaxInstrs = LOOP_COUNTER; // helps to stop infinite/runaway loops

    // header data is finished, subtract the filesize with the bytecount
    // and data segment size to get the size of our instruction stream.
    // If the instruction stream is invalid, we can't load the script.
    printf("[Tagha Load Script Ptr] :: Header Byte Count: %" PRIu32 "\n", bytecount);
    pSys->m_uiInstrSize = Programsize - bytecount - datasize;

    pSys->m_uiMemsize = stacksize + datasize + pSys->m_uiInstrSize;
    pSys->m_pMemory = calloc(pSys->m_uiMemsize, sizeof(uint8_t));

    // scripts NEED memory, if memory is invalid then we can't use the script.
    if( !pSys->m_pMemory ) {
        printf("[%sTagha Load Script Error%s]: **** %sFailed to allocate memory for script%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
        Tagha_Free(pSys);
        return;
    }

    /*  +------------------+
        |    stack   |     |      highest address
        |            v     |
        |                  |
        |                  |
        |                  |
        |                  |
        |                  |
        |                  |
        +------------------+      stack segment
        | data segment     |
        +------------------+
        | text segment     |      lowest address
        +------------------+
    */
    // set up the stack ptrs to the top of the stack.
    pSys->m_Regs[rsp].UCharPtr = pSys->m_Regs[rbp].UCharPtr = pSys->m_pMemory + (pSys->m_uiMemsize-1);

    // set up our stack segment by taking the top of the stack and subtracting it with the size.
    pSys->m_pStackSegment = pSys->m_Regs[rsp].UCharPtr - (stacksize-1);

    // set up the data segment by taking the stack segment - 1
    pSys->m_pDataSegment = pSys->m_pStackSegment - 1;

    // set up the text segment similar to how the stack ptrs are set up
    pSys->m_pTextSegment = pSys->m_pMemory + (pSys->m_uiInstrSize-1);

    // copy the initialized values to the data segment if there's any global values.
    memcpy(pSys->m_pTextSegment+1, Reader.Ptr, pSys->m_pDataSegment-pSys->m_pTextSegment);
    Reader.UCharPtr += pSys->m_pDataSegment-pSys->m_pTextSegment;

    // instruction stream is valid, copy every last instruction.
    memcpy(pSys->m_pMemory, Reader.Ptr, pSys->m_uiInstrSize);

    puts("\n");
}

void Tagha_Free(struct Tagha *restrict const pSys)
{
    if( !pSys )
        return;

    // kill memory
    FREE_MEM(pSys->m_pMemory);

    // free our native table
    uint32_t i, Size;
    if( pSys->m_pstrNativeCalls ) {
        for( i=0 ; i<pSys->m_uiNatives ; i++ ) {
            FREE_MEM(pSys->m_pstrNativeCalls[i]);
        }
        memset(pSys->m_pstrNativeCalls, 0, pSys->m_uiNatives);
        FREE_MEM(pSys->m_pstrNativeCalls);
    }
    // free our C definitions hashmap and all the tables in it.
    if( pSys->m_pmapCDefs ) {
        struct KeyNode
            *restrict kv = NULL,
            *next = NULL
        ;
        Size = pSys->m_pmapCDefs->size;
        for( i=0 ; i<Size ; i++ ) {
            for( kv = pSys->m_pmapCDefs->m_ppTable[i] ; kv ; kv = next ) {
                next = kv->m_pNext;
                if( kv->m_pData )
                    free((struct TaghaCDef *)(uintptr_t)kv->m_pData), kv->m_pData = 0;
                if( kv->m_strKey )
                    free((char *)kv->m_strKey), kv->m_strKey = NULL;
            }
        }
        Map_Free(pSys->m_pmapCDefs);
        FREE_MEM(pSys->m_pmapCDefs);
    }

    // since the system's native hashmap has nothing allocated,
    // we just free the hashmap's internal data and then the hashmap itself.
    if( pSys->m_pmapNatives ) {
        Map_Free(pSys->m_pmapNatives);
        FREE_MEM(pSys->m_pmapNatives);
    }

    // free our script argument vector.
    if( pSys->m_pArgv ) {
        for( uint32_t i=0 ; i<pSys->m_iArgc ; i++ )
            FREE_MEM(pSys->m_pArgv[i].Str);
        FREE_MEM(pSys->m_pArgv);
    }

    // set our stack pointer pointers to NULL
    pSys->m_Regs[rip].UCharPtr = pSys->m_Regs[rsp].UCharPtr = pSys->m_Regs[rbp].UCharPtr = NULL;
}


void Tagha_Reset(struct Tagha *restrict const pSys)
{
    if( !pSys )
        return;

    // resets the script without crashing Tagha and the host.
    memset(pSys->m_pTextSegment+1, 0, pSys->m_uiMemsize-pSys->m_uiInstrSize);
    pSys->m_Regs[rsp].UCharPtr = pSys->m_Regs[rbp].UCharPtr = pSys->m_pMemory + (pSys->m_uiMemsize-1);

    memset(pSys->m_Regs, 0, sizeof(union CValue) * rsp);
    // TODO: reset global variable data to original values?
}


void *Tagha_GetGlobalByName(const struct Tagha *restrict const pSys, const char *restrict strGlobalName)
{
    if( !pSys or !pSys->m_pmapCDefs )
        return NULL;

    // get the global's .data segment offset then return the pointer to that offset.
    struct TaghaCDef *pOffset = (struct TaghaCDef *)(uintptr_t)Map_Get(pSys->m_pmapCDefs, strGlobalName);
    return pOffset and pOffset->m_ucDefType==DefGlobal ? (pSys->m_pTextSegment+1)+ pOffset->m_uiOffset : NULL;
}

void Tagha_PushValues(struct Tagha *restrict const pSys, const uint32_t uiArgs, union CValue values[])
{
    if( !pSys or !pSys->m_pMemory )
        return;

    // remember that arguments must be passed right to left.
    // we have enough args to fit in registers.
    if( uiArgs <= 10 ) {
        memcpy(pSys->m_Regs+rds, values, sizeof(union CValue)*uiArgs);
    }
    // we have too many args, use both regs and stack.
    else if( uiArgs>10 ) {
        // first push args into reg.
        memcpy(pSys->m_Regs+rds, values, sizeof(union CValue)*10);

        // next, push the remaining values from last to first.
        if( pSys->m_bSafeMode and (pSys->m_Regs[rsp].SelfPtr-(uiArgs-10)) < (union CValue *)pSys->m_pStackSegment ) {
            Tagha_PrintErr(pSys, __func__, "stack overflow!");
            return;
        }
        memcpy(pSys->m_Regs[rsp].SelfPtr, values+10, sizeof(union CValue)*(uiArgs-10));
        pSys->m_Regs[rsp].SelfPtr -= (uiArgs-10);
    }
}

union CValue Tagha_PopValue(struct Tagha *restrict const pSys)
{
    union CValue val={ .UInt64=0L };
    if( !pSys or !pSys->m_pMemory ) {
        printf("[%sTagha Pop%s]: **** %pSys is NULL%s ****\n", KRED, RESET, KGRN, RESET);
        return val;
    }
    return pSys->m_Regs[ras];
}

void Tagha_SetCmdArgs(struct Tagha *restrict const pSys, char *argv[])
{
    if( !pSys or !pSys->m_pMemory or !argv )
        return;

    // clear old arguments, if any.
    for( uint32_t i=0 ; i<pSys->m_iArgc ; i++ )
        FREE_MEM(pSys->m_pArgv[i].Str);

    // get the size of argument vector
    uint32_t newargc = 0;
    while( argv[++newargc] != NULL );

    // resize our system's argument vector.
    if( pSys->m_iArgc != newargc ) {
        pSys->m_iArgc = newargc;
        FREE_MEM(pSys->m_pArgv);
        pSys->m_pArgv = calloc(pSys->m_iArgc+1, sizeof(union CValue));
    }

    /* For Implementing 'int argc' and 'char *argv[]'
     * C Standards dictates the following...
     * - The value of argc shall be nonnegative.
     * - The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall be modifiable by the program
     * - argv[argc] shall be a null pointer.
     * - If the value of argc is greater than zero, the array members argv[0] through argv[argc-1] inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup.
     * - If the value of argc is greater than zero, the string pointed to by argv[0] represents the program name; argv[0][0] shall be the null character if the program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of argc is greater than one, the strings pointed to by argv[1] through argv[argc-1] represent the program parameters.
    */

    // Copy down our argument vector's strings.
    for( uint32_t i=0 ; i<pSys->m_iArgc ; i++ ) {
        size_t strsize = strlen(argv[i])+1;
        pSys->m_pArgv[i].Str = calloc(strsize, sizeof(char));

        if( pSys->m_pArgv[i].Str ) {
            strncpy(pSys->m_pArgv[i].Str, argv[i], strsize);
            pSys->m_pArgv[i].Str[strsize-1] = 0;
        }
    }
    pSys->m_pArgv[pSys->m_iArgc].Str = NULL;
}


uint32_t Tagha_GetMemSize(const struct Tagha *restrict const pSys)
{
    return !pSys ? 0 : pSys->m_uiMemsize;
}
uint32_t Tagha_GetInstrSize(const struct Tagha *restrict const pSys)
{
    return !pSys ? 0 : pSys->m_uiInstrSize;
}
uint32_t Tagha_GetMaxInstrs(const struct Tagha *restrict const pSys)
{
    return !pSys ? 0 : pSys->m_uiMaxInstrs;
}
uint32_t Tagha_GetNativeCount(const struct Tagha *restrict const pSys)
{
    return !pSys ? 0 : pSys->m_uiNatives;
}
uint32_t Tagha_GetFuncCount(const struct Tagha *restrict const pSys)
{
    return !pSys ? 0 : pSys->m_uiFuncs;
}
uint32_t Tagha_GetGlobalsCount(const struct Tagha *restrict const pSys)
{
    return !pSys ? 0 : pSys->m_uiGlobals;
}
bool Tagha_IsSafemodeActive(const struct Tagha *restrict const pSys)
{
    return !pSys ? 0 : pSys->m_bSafeMode;
}
bool Tagha_IsDebugActive(const struct Tagha *restrict const pSys)
{
    return !pSys ? 0 : pSys->m_bDebugMode;
}



void Tagha_PrintStack(const struct Tagha *restrict const pSys)
{
    if( !pSys or !pSys->m_pMemory )
        return;

    puts("DEBUG PRINT: .stack Segment\n");

    uint32_t size = pSys->m_uiMemsize;
    union CValue *p = (union CValue *)(pSys->m_pMemory + (size-1));

    while( (uint8_t *)p >= pSys->m_pStackSegment ) {
        if( pSys->m_Regs[rsp].SelfPtr == p )
            printf("Stack[%.10" PRIu32 "] == %" PRIu64 " - T.O.S.\n", (uint8_t *)p-pSys->m_pMemory, p->UInt64);
        else printf("Stack[%.10" PRIu32 "] == %" PRIu64 "\n", (uint8_t *)p-pSys->m_pMemory, p->UInt64);
        --p;
    } /* while( p>=pSys->m_pStackSegment ) */
    puts("\n");
}

void Tagha_PrintData(const struct Tagha *restrict const pSys)
{
    if( !pSys or !pSys->m_pMemory )
        return;

    puts("DEBUG PRINT: .data Segment\n");
    for( uint8_t *p = pSys->m_pDataSegment ; p > pSys->m_pTextSegment ; --p )
        printf("Data[%.10" PRIu32 "] == %" PRIu32 "\n", p-pSys->m_pMemory, *p);

    puts("\n");
}

void Tagha_PrintInstrs(const struct Tagha *restrict const pSys)
{
    if( !pSys or !pSys->m_pMemory )
        return;

    puts("DEBUG PRINT: .text Segment\n");
    for( uint8_t *p = pSys->m_pMemory ; p <= pSys->m_pTextSegment ; p++ )
        printf("Text[%.10" PRIu32 "] == %" PRIu32 "\n", p-pSys->m_pMemory, *p);

    puts("\n");
}

void Tagha_PrintPtrs(const struct Tagha *restrict const pSys)
{
    if( !pSys )
        return;

    puts("DEBUG ...---===---... Printing Pointers...\n");
    printf("Instruction Ptr: %p\
            \nStack Ptr: %p\
            \nStack Frame Ptr: %p\n", pSys->m_Regs[rip].UCharPtr, pSys->m_Regs[rsp].UCharPtr, pSys->m_Regs[rbp].UCharPtr);
    puts("\n");
}

void Tagha_PrintErr(const struct Tagha *restrict const pSys, const char *restrict funcname, const char *restrict err, ...)
{
    if( !pSys or !err )
        return;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, err);
    printf("[%sTagha Error%s]: **** %s reported: \'", KRED, KNRM, funcname);
    vprintf(err, args);
    va_end(args);
    printf("\' ****\nCurrent Instr Addr: %s%p | offset: %" PRIuPTR "%s\n", KGRN, pSys->m_Regs[rip].UCharPtr, pSys->m_Regs[rip].UCharPtr-pSys->m_pMemory, RESET);

    // do a stack trace by using rbp as a linked list to older rbp frames.
    printf("[%sTagha Stack Trace%s]:\n", KYEL, KNRM);
    for( union CValue *iter=pSys->m_Regs[rbp].SelfPtr ;
            (uint8_t *)iter >= pSys->m_pStackSegment and (uint8_t *)iter < pSys->m_pMemory+pSys->m_uiMemsize ;
            iter = iter->SelfPtr )
        printf("[%s%p%s]\n", KGRN, iter, RESET);

    printf("======== %sTagha Stack Trace END%s ========\n", KYEL, KNRM);
}

void Tagha_PrintRegData(const struct Tagha *restrict const pSys)
{
    puts("\n\tPRINTING REGISTER DATA ==========================\n");
    for( uint8_t i=0 ; i<regsize ; i++ )
        printf("register[%s] == %" PRIu64 "\n", RegIDToStr(i), pSys->m_Regs[i].UInt64);
    puts("\tEND OF PRINTING REGISTER DATA ===============\n");
}
```

Comment: What do you want from this review?

Comment: @chux well I posted on the OP that I wanted a review of the overall design and structure for the entire software but a mod removed that for some reason.

Comment: Why `restrict` in `is_c_file()`?

Comment: Code does not compile as `tagha.h` is missing from this post.  Off-site material is not sufficient.  Better to include enough code here so it may compiled even if it can not linked.

Comment: @chux `tagha.h` is in the github repository. Alright, I'll add it to the OP.

Comment: It may be good  to add that tagha.h is not there for review, but to allow a compile.  IOWs `tagha_api.c` is for review.  Of course you may want all/part tagha.h reviewed - up to you.  BTW, code compiles.

Answer (score 1):

Some quick reviewed parts using a compilation with warnings fully enabled.

What is a bit cheesy about this is that a grader could first take your code and run it through a compiler with lots of warnings enabled.  Your code made about 80 warnings.  Lots of minor ones.  Some of the more significant ones are summarized below.  But is is like a term paper with spelling/grammar errors.  All those warnings (some minor, others trivial) distract from your presentation.  Advice: Compile code with maximum warnings enabled and clean up code.

1. `static bool is_c_file()` and `static bool is_tbc_file()` not used.  Consider deleting.
2. Why does code use `uint32_t` for size information such as `bytecount` and others instead of `size_t`?  It the goal to work on 32-bit platforms or smaller?  `size_t` is the best type for size and array math being neither too wide nor too narrow.
3. Mis-match format various places such as `PRIu32` used, `PRIu8` expected.

   ```
   printf("Stack[%.10" PRIu32 "] == %" PRIu64 " - T.O.S.\n", (uint8_t *)p-pSys->m_pMemory, p->UInt64);
   else printf("Stack[%.10" PRIu32 "] == %" PRIu64 "\n", (uint8_t *)p-pSys->m_pMemory, p->UInt64);
   ...
   printf("Data[%.10" PRIu32 "] == %" PRIu32 "\n", p-pSys-> s->m_pMemory, *p);
   ... 
   printf("Text[%.10" PRIu32 "] == %" PRIu32 "\n", p-pSys->m_pMemory, *p);
   ```
4. Code does a lot of `bytecount += sizeof(some_tpye)`.  Why that type?  Is it because of the previous line like `pSys->m_uiFuncs = ...`.  If so, consider rather than adding the size of the type, add the size of the object.  It is easier to code, review and maintain.

   ```
   pSys->m_uiFuncs = *Reader.UInt32Ptr++;
   // bytecount += sizeof(uint32_t);
   bytecount += sizeof pSys->m_uiFuncs;
   ```
5. Similar to above.  Why `sizeof(uint32_t)`?  Is it the right type?  Use the sizeof the object and remove doubt.

   ```
   // ignores = fread(&str_size, sizeof(uint32_t), 1, *ppFile);
   ignores = fread(&str_size, sizeof *str_size, 1, *ppFile);
   ```
6. Casting hides problems.  Example below.  `ftell()` return a `long`.  And with a value of -1 is an error

   ```
   if( !fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END) ) {
       // size = (uint64_t)ftell(pFile);
       long lsize = ftell(pFile);
       if (lsize == -1) TBD_code();
       size =  (uint64_t)lsize;
       rewind(pFile);
   }
   ```

More later as time permits.

Comment: Alright, all the suggested changes have been done except for deleting unused functions, I feel they may be useful in the future as I develop Tagha further. I've enabled `-Wall`  for the compiling scripts. Nothing in Tagha's core code uses `size_t` except for line 904 in tagha_api.c: `size_t strsize = strlen(argv[i])+1;` What are you talking about having others use `size_t`?

Is there anything else that can be done possibly?

Comment: @Nergal Re: unused functions (dead code).  A well warning enabled compile will continue to warn.  By leaving in dead code, it encourages either 1) ignoring warnings or 2) not fully enabling warnings - both of these are undesirable practices.  IMO, simple `#if 0 ... #endif` the dead code if it remains useful for reference.  Adding a comment for their retention is useful too.

Comment: @Nergal Tagha's  code uses `uint32_t` for the "size" of things as part of a "file" structure.  Using a fixed width type for  a file has benefits and is usually "good".  Using `size_t` for sizes in memory is better - how to reconcile the 2 is where could generates lots of warnings as those 2 types are not necessarily the same range/size.  More study need study of code needed.

Comment: Tip for always compiling with warnings put this in your .bashrc: `CFLAGS+='-pedantic-errors -Wall'` then compile with `make` which uses that variable in default rules.